# Tracing recursive calls in java?

Tags: java, recursion, stack

How do recursive calls work with stacks? I have this sample code in which line `B` prints  `B 654321`, `c` prints `C`, `d` prints  `D 2468` and `e` throws an exception. I do not understand why the program is printing those outputs! For instance, in line B, doesn't `s` become `0` as a result of the stack? Thank you

```
public class Problem1 { 
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Stack<Integer> s = setStack(5); printStack("A",      s); // line A 
    s = setStack(6); stackStack(s); printStack("B", s); // line B 
    s = setStack(8); cutStack(s); printStack("C", s); // line C 
    s = setStack(8); s = cutStack(s); printStack("D", s); // line D 
    s = setStack(7); s = cutStack(s); printStack("E", s); // line E 
} 
public static Stack<Integer> setStack(int n) {     
  Stack<Integer> ans = new Stack<>(); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        ans.push(i); 
    return ans; 
    }
public static void printStack(String tag, Stack<Integer> s) { 
  System.out.print(tag + " "); 
  while (!s.empty()) System.out.print(s.pop());    
  System.out.println(); 
 } 
public static Stack<Integer> cutStack(Stack<Integer> s)  
  { 
  Stack<Integer> ans = new Stack<>(); 
  while (!s.empty()) { 
     ans.push(s.pop()); 
     s.pop();
  } 
  s = ans; return s;
} 
public static void stackStack(Stack<Integer> s) { 
   if (s.empty()) return; 
   int x = s.pop(); 
   stackStack(s); 
   s.push(x); 
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but what I think you want to do is NOT `s.pop()` twice in a row. That's what's causing the error on Stacks with an odd amount of values. It keeps popping twice in a row until there's 1 left, then it pops twice in a row once again, meaning the second time it will be an empty stack you're trying to pop
This is in method `cutStack(Stack<Integer>):Stack<Integer>`

Comment: Why would `s` become `0` *(whatever that means)* when calling `stackStack`, which `push` everything back that it `pop`? --- Did you mean "become empty" when you said "become 0"? --- Anyway, explain *why* you think it should be empty/0/whatever.

Comment: Also stackStack wouldn't end up empty since you push `x` back into `s` before the end of the method

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. This was a review question that my professor gave out. The student is supposed to predict the output regardless of what it is. I meant become empty. Because when the stackStack is called recursively, doesn't it keep becoming smaller until it reaches 0? Thus it never reaches the s.push() line?

Comment: The last iteration in the recursive loop (when `s` is empty) doesn't reach the push line, the method just ends. But then the previous method that was waiting for the next one to finish gets to reach `s.push(x)`, so multiple values do indeed get pushed to `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stackStack, consider a smaller stack: 123 (with 3 on the top of the stack).
Let F1 be the first call to `stackStack()`, F2 be the nested call, and so on.

F1: `stackStack(123)` pops out the 3 and stores it in x. So `x_1=3` and `s=12`

F2: `stackStack(12)` is now called. So `x_2=2` and `s=1`

F3: Now `stackStack(1)` is called. Now, `x_3=1` and `s` is empty.

Now, `s` is empty. So the control simply returns to F3.

F3 then pushes `x_3 =1` onto the empty `s`. So `s=1` and the control returns to F2.

F2 pushes `x_2=2` onto `s=1`. So `s=12` and the control returns to F1.

F1 pushes `x_1=3` onto `s=12`. So `s=123`.

You've just ended up with the original stack and `printStack()` simply prints out 321.

This should give you an idea of how recursion works in general.

Comment: When stackStack(2) is called, how is the value of x still 32? Because didn't we permanently change it to 3 before?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. stackStack takes a stack as input and x is simply an integer. Each time stackStack is called, it resides in a seperate location in memory. So there are actually multiple x's, one for each call to stackStack().